# Custom CSS for Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: google-api, google-search-api, jsapi

How can I customize CSS for Google Search Engine. Currently I use a theme:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('search', '1', 
         {language : 'en', style : google.loader.themes.ESPRESSO});
.....
```

But I want to change the font colors/sizes.

On the official guide https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-devguide

I see a link:

- Modify result CSS properties - The Custom Search element uses [Search Control result styles](https://developers.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/#StylingSearchResults), which you can modify to change basic look and feel.

Which is broken (leads to 404). Surfing the Internet didn't bring results. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They just moved it under another URL but forgot to update it in their documentation:

was

https://developers.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/#StylingSearchResults

became

https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/#StylingSearchResults

Comment: They changed the url again?